# Почему в кратком прилагательном "достоин" пишется буква И?

Tags: орфография

**Цитата (из форума):** 
Удостоить - удостоенный - удостоен, но достойный - достоин. Это слово часто пишут через букву е, по всей видимости, обращаясь к правилу, гласящему, что краткие прилагательные, образованные от полных прилагательных на ЙНЫЙ, пишутся через букву Е (необычаЙНЫЙ - необычаЕН, благопристоЙНЫЙ - благопристоЕН, строЙНЫЙ - строЕН).
**Но в русском языке есть исключение и из этого правила,** а именно: краткие прилагательные ДОСТОИН, НЕДОСТОИН  пишутся через букву И.

**А почему в русском языке есть исключение и из этого правила?** Хотелось бы по возможности обходиться без исключений или объяснять эти исключения.

Спасибо за ваши ответы.

Comment: Наверное, чтобы рифмовалось с "воин"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Может быть потому, что исходит из другого и составляет ему компанию — **достоинство**. Такое слово неправильно писать затруднительно, и в известной степени оно может считаться проверочным.

Comment: Да, у меня тоже были похожие мысли.  Словообразовательная схема: достойный - достоинство, суффикс существительного СТВ, звук Й естественным образом переходит в  звук И. Ну а  в глаголе "удостоить (посчитать достойным) также пишется И. Только в кратком причастии мы имеем переход И/ЕНН.

Answer (score 5):

А у нас сладкая парочка: ***удостоенный*** и ***достойный***...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Своровано [отсель](http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/1771531-pochemu-slovo-udostoen-pishetsja-cherez-e-kak-pravilno-udostoen-ili-udostoin.html).

---

Нашёлся ответ на "почему?":

[это разные части речи и у них разные суффиксы](http://www.seznaika.ru/russkiy/olimpiada/1764--9-).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Простое повторение уже приведённого материала.  Вопрос был: "**А *почему* в русском языке есть исключение и из этого правила?**"

Comment: Как известно, на вопрос "почему?" наука ответа не даёт. Исключения просто усваиваются.

Comment: Если наука Вам ответа не дала, это не значит, что ответа нет.

Comment: Галина, а откуда  такие странные эмоции: "своровано отсель". Думаю, что это не тот стиль, который можно позволить себе на этом ресурсе. Кажется, я указываю, что это цитата из форума. И в этом ответе меня как раз не устраивает это преклонение перед исключениями, которые не витамины, чтобы мы их усваивали.  Разумеется, есть причина,  по которой здесь пишется буква И, но вот в чем она заключается? Кроме того, если я не ошибаюсь, этот вопрос ставился в ходе несостоявшейся реформы 2001 года, но так и остался нерешенным и открытым для обсуждения.

Comment: >> *а откуда такие странные эмоции: "своровано отсель". Думаю, что это не тот стиль, который можно позволить себе на этом ресурсе.* Ну, давайте будем всегда скучными занудами... На ресурсе Академии наук, возможно, это и не тот стиль.

Comment: Niemand, тут дело не в стиле, разумеется, это я для красоты слога так пишу. На самом деле, эта трактовка "своровано отсель" мне кажется нелепой, неожиданной, не соответствующей действительности, да  и просто оскорбительной.  А вы считаете, что всё нормально?

Comment: Абсолютно. А для кого оскорбительно-то? И почему это "трактовка"?

Comment: Вера, это действительно мой стиль - полная свобода использования всех пластов лексики.

Comment: Начала «сладкой» парочкой, логично и закруглила. Было хорошее настроение, не более того. Так думается.

Comment: shampar, правильно думается! )))

Comment: Галина, а откуда такие фантазии на тему суффикса прилагательного  ИН? Суффикс прилагательного  ИН имеет исключительно притяжательное значение: дядя - дядин,  комар - комариный, и это всё. В прилагательном достойный выделяется суффикс Н, а И/Й относится к корню.

Comment: И по поводу "всех пластов лексики". Я думаю, что разные стили  - это большое достоинство нашего языка. Они  как раз и существуют для того, чтобы в разных ситуациях мы использовали разные приемы речи и не говорили с незнакомым человеком на том же наречии, на котором говорим со своими друзьями.

Comment: 1). Фантазии на тему суффикса - из олимпиадного задания по вполне себе кликабельной ссылке. 2). Я сама выбираю, в какой стилистике мне удобнее общаться. Если кого-то это обстоятельство не устраивает, он абсолютно волен презреть и отсутствие стилистического жеманства, и его непроизводителя.

Comment: Почему-то вольнолюбивый Аксёнов назвал наречие для незнакомого человека ВээМПээСом им. Тургенева.

Answer (score 5):

> Почему в кратком прилагательном “достоин” пишется буква И?

Из **Грота**: *по примеру древнеславянского языка, как бы для отличия от причастия **удостоен**.*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Мне тоже сначала подумалось, что мы просто формы различаем, но потом это показалось не очень убедительным.

Answer (score 4):

Все исключения связаны с традицией, т.е. с историей языка, часто с этимологией. Если обратиться к этимологии слова "достойный", мы увидим, что современное слово развилось из др.-р. дост**о**иныи(ст**о**ящий)вследствие изменения И в Й, это полная форма к краткой : достоинъ, достоина,достоино. Форма кр.прил. достоино стала наречием достойно ( устаревшее значение "с достоинством").

Форма достоинъ образована с суф. -ьн- от сущ. достой,
известного в рус. диал. со знач. "приличие", "то, чего ст**о**ит чел. или дело".

Само сущ. достой образовано путем усечения основы глаг. достоити "надлежит,
приличествует, соответствует", известного в рус. диал. и в свою очередь
производного с прист. до- со знач. достижения результата, конца, завершения
действия (как достать) от глаг. ст**о**ити, (от стоять). Ср. рус. диал. стойный "ст**о**ящий, достойный, чтимый". От прил. достойный
с пом. приставки у- и суфф. -и-ть образован глаг. удостоить (как прочный-упрочить)"признать достойным" " соврем, удостоить "признав достойным, наградить чем-либо, присвоить какое-либо звание, степень". А уже от глагола - причастие удостоенный - по всем правилам: на -ить, значит, суфф.-енн-.

[АБЗАЦ: Этимологический словарь РУССКОГО ЯЗЫКА / Цыганенко Г. П.](http://lib.co.ua/dict/cyganenkogp/etimologicheskiyslovarrusskogo.jsp)

Comment: От сущ.достой у нас осталось также книжное "достопочтенный, досточтимый"

Comment: В русском письме в основном поддерживаются те традиции, которые можно объяснить с точки зрения современного языка. Рассмотрим примеры: (1)  спокойный - спокоен - спокойствие, благопристойный - благопристоен -  благопристойность, (2) достойный - достоин - достоинство.  В существительном "достоинство" переход Й в И, аналогичную запись имеет форма "достоин". Если бы не было существительного "достоинство", то традиция письма для "достоин" вряд ли бы сохранилась, не было бы никакого смысла ее поддерживать.

Comment: Я отвечала на Ваш вопрос :А почему в русском языке есть исключение и из этого правила?  А Вы рассуждаете по поводу того, почему др.-р. достоинъ, достоиныи не изменили написание в современности, не превратились в достоенный, достоен. На это Вам уже ответили, чтобы не слилось с причастием удостоенный, значения-то разные: "обладающий положительными качествами" и "награждённый". Да и вообще, почему слово должно менять свой вид, под что-то подстраиваться? Кто не понимает, пусть тот и вдумывается, почему так.

Comment: 1) Вы в своем ответе утверждали, что  ВСЕ исключения связаны с традицией, а я в своем комментарии говорила о том, что для сохранения традиции нужны дополнительные основания.  2) И по поводу этого исключения высказывались РАЗЛИЧНЫЕ мнения.  Давайте тогда будем писать: достойный - достоин - удостоен, спокойный - спокоин - успокоен, чтобы причастие ОТЛИЧАЛОСЬ от прилагательного. 3) Форум для того и существует, чтобы совместно обсуждать спорные вопросы, а не "вдумываться" поодиночке. 4) У Вас есть свобода выбора: если Вы с кем-то не нашли общей точки зрения, то лучше и не продолжать разговор.

Comment: Вера, да какие там основания и какие общие точки зрения, если Вам важна только своя точка зрения. С Вами я спорить и не собираюсь, смешно было бы, если б признали меня правой. Обидно, что путаете людей, они ведь Вас за профессионала принимают и безоговорочно верят, Никаких дополнительных оснований здесь не нужно, нужны основания, чтобы что-то изменить, а не сохранить. И ещё, странно, что Вы соединяете достоин, образованное от сущ.(достой) с другими краткими прилагательными на -ен от полной формы на -ный, ведь все они образованы от страдат. причастий

Comment: Только здесь тоже нужно "лезть"в историю слов, а Вы пытаетесь судить с позиций современности.Знойный-от зноить (пламенеть), спокойный-от покоить, стройный - от строить. Многие образованы калькированием от иностранных глаголов. Нужно разбирать каждое слово отдельно, а не судить огульно и приводить внешне выглядящие похоже слова к одному типу словоизменения.

Answer (score 2):

Думаю, что здесь "И" потому, что весьма сильна связь между "достоин" - "достоинство" - "стоить".

Comment: Скорее всего, именно "достоинство"  задает вариант с буквой И. Мы же пишем: благопристойный - благопристоен, возможно, потому что слова "благопристоинство"  нет.

Answer (score 0):

Итак, вопрос остается открытым. В качестве итога приведу следующую цитату из форума: http://www.ljpoisk.ru/archive/457274.html

"**Вопрос 839:** В кратком причастии "удостоен" в суффиксе пишется "е", а в однокоренном кратком прилагательном "достоин" пишется "и". Понятно, что в последнем случае "и" входит в состав корня, т. к. это трансформация "й" из полного прилагательного "достойный". Но почему именно "и", а не "е", как в аналогичных случаях: спокойный - спокоен, знойный - зноен?

**Ответ:** В руководствах по правописанию слово "достоин" рассматривается просто как исключение (так, в частности, и в монографии А.Б. Шапиро "Русское правописание" (М., 1951, с.68). С**обственно говоря, принятое сейчас написание установил Грот, чтобы разграничить прилагательное и причастие (хотя для этого достаточно приставки: ср. спокоен-успокоен).** **На это слово нападали почти все реформаторы правописания.** Вместе со словом "заяц", которое создает те же проблемы. **Предлагали писать "достоен" и в Проекте 1964 г.** (Подробнее см. Обзор предложений по усовершенствованию русской орфографии. М., 1965. С. 294-295). Но у нас есть все же смутное ощущение, что какие-то резоны в пользу "достоИн" привести можно. Будем думать дальше!"

Comment: Не надо думать дальше. Как раз тот случай, когда говорят: "Так сложилось!". Грот предложил, либо кто-то еще до него - неважно. Так хорошо, естественно и (!)красиво.И так и останется.